# Getting number of reviews from table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get number of reviews from table (review). Here is my database structure and some code I am using:

**review table**

```
------------------------
| id | bizid | content |
------------------------
```

**biz table**

```
----------------
| id | bizname |
----------------
```

**code**

```
Class Reviews extends MY_model {
    public function get_biz_id() {
        $query = $this->db->query("select * from biz");
        $id =$query->result();
        return $id;
    }
    
            public function get_count_reviews($c) {
                    $this->db->select('COUNT(review.id) AS reviewCount');
                    $this->db->join('review', 'review.bizid = biz.id');
                    $this->db->where('bizid', $c);
                    $query = $this->db->get('biz');
                    if ($query->num_rows() < 1) return FALSE;
                    $res = $query->row_array();
                    return $res['reviewCount'];
           }
}
```

Local Controller

```
Class Local extends CI_controller {

    public function city() {
        $this->load->model('reviews');                 
        $b = $this->reviews->get_biz_id();
        foreach($b as $bb) {
            $bbb = $bb->id;
            $data['count_reviews'] = $this->reviews->get_count_reviews($bbb);
            $this->load->view('local/index',$data);
        }
        $data['reviews'] = $this->reviews->get_city_reviews($city->id,5,1);
    }

}
```

This one is the view:

```
<?php
foreach($reviews as $review):               
$biz = getBizById($review->bizid);
?>
<li class="clearfix">
    <div class="span-1">
        <a href="<?=site_url('member/'.$review->username)?>">
            <img class="thumbimg thumb40" src="<?=site_url(avatar($review->uid))?>"/>
        </a>
    </div>
            
    <div class="span-13">
        <div class="title-name">
            <a  href="<?=site_url('member/'.$review->username)?>"><?php echo ucfirst($review->username)?></a> reviewed
            <a href="<?=site_url('biz/'.$biz->id)?>#review_<?php echo $review->id ?>"><?=$biz->name?></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="span-3 rating-wrap rating-<?php echo $review->rating ?>"></div>
        <div><?php echo $count_reviews;  ?></div>
                
        <p class="clear"><?=wordwrap($review->content,55,"<br>\n")?></p>
            
    </div>

</li> 
<?php endforeach;?>
```

I wanna echo number of reviews `($count_reviews)` next to `<div class ="span-3">`, but since I also need to echo other things I have to use `foreach()`, and that is where my issue started.

**The output**

MC Donald's
Number of reviews  (1)

Jemmy Johns
Number of reviews  (1)

KFC
Number of reviews  (1)

Even thought only MC Donald 's that has one review

Thanks

Comment: i think you should put the content of **class Local** inside a function.

Comment: @Vainglory07 Yeah, I just forgot it when typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JOIN to get the review count:

```
public function get_count_reviews($c) {
        $this->db->select('COUNT(review.id) AS reviewCount');
        $this->db->join('review', 'review.bizid = biz.id');
        $this->db->where('bizid', $c);
        $query = $this->db->get('biz');
        if ($query->num_rows() < 1) return FALSE;
        $res = $query->row_array();
        return $res['reviewCount'];
    }
```

Also make change in city function in controller like below

```
foreach($b as $bb) {
            $bbb = $bb->id;
            $data['count_reviews'][$bb->id] = $this->reviews->get_count_reviews($bbb);//save all instead of overwriting
            $this->load->view('local/index',$data);
}
```

And in your `view`

```
<div><?php echo (isset($count_reviews[$biz->id]))?$count_reviews[$biz->id]:0;  ?></div>
```

Comment: I've tried that also, sorry I didn't mention it. I keep getting on row

Comment: What do you mean by row? please put the output

Comment: you will only get the count of reviews for any one business, where bizid = your passed id

Comment: Like I said above, jimmy johns has 3, KFC has 5, MC donald's has 1. So far it only return the first row